# Как ускорить движение объекта?

Tags: swift

В сцене пальцем можно перемещать объект. Но если чуть ускорить перемещение пальца по экрану - объект остается на месте. Можно ли ускорить скорость его перемещения? Duration уже установил на 0

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch!.locationInNode(self)
    let node = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

    if (node.name == "circle") {

        let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(touchLocation, duration: 0)

        figureUser.runAction(moveAction)
    }
}
```

Comment: я так понимаю, когда вы быстро перемещаете палец, он выходит за границы вашего node, и if игнорирует перемещение. можете это проверить?

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Ниже уже есть 2 решения

Comment: когда я комментировал решений еще не было :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алгоритм перемещения у вас не совсем правильный, хотя мысль верная. Суть в том, что в touchesMoved при быстром перемещении пальца следующая точка касания может оказаться в 200-300 точках от предыдущей. Это явно за пределами текущего положения объекта `node`.

Что же с этим сделать? Нужно запоминать объект, к которому прикоснулся пользователь в методе `touchesBegan`, а в `touchesMoved` только передавать ему новую координату перемещения.

Например так:

```
private var movingNode: SKNode? = nil
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch: UITouch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch!.locationInNode(self)
    let node = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

    if (node.name == "circle") {
        movingNode = node
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    guard movingNode else { return }
    let touch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch!.locationInNode(self)
    let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(touchLocation, duration: 0)
    figureUser.runAction(moveAction)
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    movingNode = nil
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Отличный способ! Я решив вопрос немножко похожим путем, ниже опубликую код.

Comment: Хотя есть небольшие проблемы с кодом... в двух определенных участках на экране, когда на них попадает нод - он резко перемещается в противоположный угол... Но это проблема и с моим кодом ниже. Странно... Может баг икскода

Answer (score 0):

```
    var movingNode : SKNode?
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)     {

    let touch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch!.locationInNode(self)
    let node = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

    if (node.name == "circle") {
        movingNode = node
        let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(touchLocation, duration: 0)

        figureUser.runAction(moveAction)
    }
}
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)     {

    let touch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch!.locationInNode(self)

        let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(touchLocation, duration: 0)

        figureUser.runAction(moveAction)

}
```

Comment: Если это финальный код, то теперь фигура будет двигаться независимо от того, попал ли пользователь первым нажатием в нее или нет, т.к. нет никаких проверок в `touchesMoved`. Ну и зануление объектов всегда хорошая практика, а то потом очень тяжело искать проблему, которой можно было избежать.

Comment: Странно, но работает только при нажатии на фигуру. В любом случае я обязательно проверю на практике и Ваш код, тем более, что про зануление объектов раньше не слышал

Comment: Да, Ваш код мне больше понравился ) Спасибо!